# java -cp with relative path not working on git-bash

Tags: java, unix, classpath

So the problem is as follows :
I have 3 java classes, A.java,B.java & C.java. Each in its own package and I'm compiling each one in a separate folder A.class in current folder, B.java in ../BFolder and C.java in ../CFolder.

A.java has a reference of B.java, and B.java has a reference of C.java.

When I run `java -cp .;../B;../C a.A` on windows cmd it works fine, But when run `java -cp .:../B:../C a.A` in a git-bash I get the error `Error : could not find or load main class a.A`.

I tried changing the order of the paths but it didn't work either. Only if I use absolute paths it works.

Comment: Could be to do with the fact that linux is case-sensitive. Are all you directory names capitalized? Also is there a need to do a.A? What about just 'A'?

Comment: Sorry I didn't give much details, actually by 'a' I meant the package. I don't think it has something to do with the case sensitivity, otherwise it wouldn't have worked with the absolute path too...right ?

Comment: Did you try making the package definition the same case as folder name? So if your folder is called 'A' then packages should be 'A'

Comment: Show **in your question** the output of `ls -lR ..` and `find .. -iname '*.java'  -exec grep package {} /dev/null \;`, both ececuted in `bash`. Also show the working example with absolute paths.